# XML Deserialization stupid issue

Tags: c#, xml

I'm looking for a way with C# which I can deserialize XML below into a class. I can read it with XmlDocument.LoadXml() but I want to deserialize it into the object.

I tried to use XmlSerializer for the object:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "properties", Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata") ]
public class MyDto
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "ObjectID", Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices")]
    public string ObjectID { get; set; }
    public string ContactID { get; set; }
}
```

My Code (memory stream is filled with xml):

```
var ms = new MemoryStream();
var w = XmlWriter.Create(ms, new XmlWriterSettings
{
    Indent = true,
    IndentChars = " ",
    OmitXmlDeclaration = false,
    Encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false),
});

XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyDto));
var data = (MyDto)serializer.Deserialize(ms);
```

but I got the error 
System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (0, 0). ---> System.Xml.XmlException: Root element is missing.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Content type="application/xml">
 <m:properties xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
  <d:ObjectID xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices">920D2</d:ObjectID>
  <d:ContactID xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices">99999</d:ContactID>
 </m:properties>
</Content>
```

Comment: I think your problem is that the XML has a root element Content, which the XMLSerializer knows nothing about.

Comment: The error is indicating the memorystream does not have the same xml file as you posted or the xml is not a the current position.  After filling memory stream you have to set the position to zero before reading in the XmlReader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class object for `XmlSerializer` quite wrong or not suitable for your XML.

You can get your proper class object for your xml from [**`xmltocsharp`**](https://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/)

Try below class object.

```
[XmlRoot("ObjectID", Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices")]
public class ObjectID
{
    [XmlAttribute("d", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
    public string D { get; set; }
    [XmlText]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("ContactID", Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices")]
public class ContactID
{
    [XmlAttribute("d", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
    public string D { get; set; }
    [XmlText]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("properties", Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata")]
public class Properties
{
    [XmlElement("ObjectID", Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices")]
    public ObjectID ObjectID { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("ContactID", Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices")]
    public ContactID ContactID { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("m", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
    public string M { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("Content")]
public class MyDto
{
    [XmlElement("properties", Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata")]
    public Properties Properties { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you, the class object was the main reason!